# What is a daemon in software?

Tags: docker

Could you please explain to me what daemon is? For instance, Docker Daemon. In Plain English. How can I think about it using real world things/objects to understand its functionality? What's the best analogy, mental model that you're using to understand it? Thank you.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Note that Daemon is german for Demon, and it was used because back in '60s-80s, computer scientists like to pretend they were wizards. lots of old computer terminology had hints of the Arcane Arts to it. this has decreased significantly as business computing has become prevalent (the whole industry has become more straight-laced), but you still see it out there on occasion.  In this case, some programmer like to imagine that they were summoning up a demon when they ask background software to perform tasks for them.

Answer (score 3):

The strict definition of a daemon in computing is any process that is not attached to an input/output terminal. So any process which runs in the background. Daemons often have a trick with `fork()` (called *daemonize*) which disassociates the daemon from the existing session, allowing it to keep running after the user that started it logs off. Compare it with a Windows service (kinda).

In a wider sense, it's mostly used to denote "server" processes, which communicate only over network connections, and not with some sort of UI in a terminal or GUI.

The Docker daemon is the part of Docker that runs continuously in the background and manages all interactions with the kernel. The `docker` command line client only interacts with the Docker daemon, but it doesn't do anything by itself. It usually communicates with the Docker daemon through a `socket`, at `/var/run/docker.sock`, and therefore is a good example of a daemon that doesn't work only through network communications.